# Pass argument in view from custom form

Tags: 7, views

I have a view content page. I want to filters its content on the base of a custom form data.
So how we can pass or filter a view content using custom form data there?

View is built on node. In this particular node we have a field type select list.
The same select list we have created in our form. Now what ever option is selected in form, we want to use it's value in view.
We also do not have idea how to use its value.

Comment: for Drupal 8???

Comment: No,In drupal 7.

Comment: I've never done it, but I think you need to do [view's integration](http://www.danielhanold.com/story/views-integration-with-your-custom-module-and-overwriting-views-handlers) for your custom form module

Comment: Expand the question with details like: What is the entity that the view is built on e.g. Node or Node revision or Taxonomy or Custom entity etc? What filter do you want to apply to your view? Is it node id filter? title filter? search? Currently there's really no way to answer your question in a meaningful way. All I can say is (in the current question format): Google it.

Comment: does the form redirect to view after submit

Comment: no @ShreyaShetty

Comment: Hello all,
I used hook_views_pre_view and altered filter's value.
This problem is resolved now.
Thank you all :)

Comment: @ArunaSingh it'd be great if you can answer your own question with a code sample of how you achieved it and accept it as the answer, this way others who run into same issue know what to do! (and the question will no longer appear on teh unanswered list)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the custom form sits in its own page. You can rewrite the output of the field, using replacement patterns, in the view to pass the required information as part of the url.

Then using hook_menu, define parameters to pass to the form

```
function hello_world_menu() {
  $items=array();
  $items['hello_world/%/%'] = array (
    'title' => 'My Custom Form',
    'page callback' => 'hello_world_form_function',
    'page arguments' => array(1,2),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
}
```